# Office 365 add-in crashing outlook

Tags: add-in, office365, outlook-addin

I am trying to create a new add-in for Microsoft Outlook (365) using Visual Studio 2015, however I am experiencing problems with the add-in being able to crash Outlook.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Project in Visual Studio 2015, of type "Outlook 2013
   and 2016 VSTO Add-in".
2. Right Click Project, Select Add, then New Item and select "Outlook
   Form Region"
3. Select "Design a new form region", click next (*this is the default option*)
4. Select a "Separate" Region as the type, click Next (*this is the
   default option*)
5. Select the default suggested name.
6. Select only Mail Message (IPM.Note) when asked which messages
   classes. (*this is the default option*)
7. Build and Run Project.
8. In Outlook create a new message.
9. Add an attachment (Word Doc). (**Adding the attachment causes the crash!**)
10. Click the button to show the form region.
11. The Form region is shown, then outlook crashes.

During the project set up, I have used all the default options suggested by VS.

Has anyone else experienced the same issues?
or could suggest any possible reasons for the crash ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the latest service pack for office including outlook 2013 ?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Office 2016, with all available updates installed.

Comment: You don't even have to actually add the attachment, if you open the attachment popup and then click in the form region it's already enough to crash outlook.. Very frustrating

Answer (score 1):

This is bug in Outlook 2016. Many users have reported this issue on MSDN.

Link here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a35065e3-89b9-4aa2-aaad-9cb02943f7a9/outlook-2016-crash-when-i-add-new-attachment-and-click-on-a-region?forum=outlookdev